# LINQ OrderBy based on row values

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say we have two tables Parent "DocumentCodes" and Child "Documents".
DocumentCodes table have columns DID,DocumentName,PrintOrder and AscOrDesc
 Documents table have columns ID,DID and EffectiveDate.We are getting datatable by joining these two tables.

We need to sort this datatable based on below rules.

1. Sort By "PrintOrder" column ascending.
2. If two or more rows  have similar "DocumentNames" value then sort by "EffeciveDate" ascending or descending based on "AscOrDesc" value.
   "AscOrDesc" column accepts only 'A' or 'D'. If value is 'A' we need to sort "EffectiveDate" ascending and if value is 'D' we need to sort "EffectiveDate" descending.

For example,

**DocumentCodes**

```
 DID     DocumentName       PrintOrder      AscOrDesc
 1        Test1               1               D
 2        Test2               2               A
 3        Test3               3               D
```

**Documents**

```
ID        DID        EffectiveDate    
 1         2           7/9/2017
 2         1           5/5/2017
 3         2           7/8/2017
 4         3           4/9/2017
```

After joining above two tables. We have DataTable.

```
ID      DocumentName EffectiveDate  PrintOrder  AscOrDesc
1         Test2        7/9/2017       2          A
2         Test1        5/5/2017       1          D
3         Test2        7/8/2017       2          A 
4         Test3        4/9/2017       3          D
```

Now After sorting this DataTable by using above rules. DataTable should look like this.

```
ID      DocumentName EffectiveDate  PrintOrder  AscOrDesc
1         Test1         5/5/2017      1           D
2         Test2         7/8/2017      2           A
3         Test2         7/9/2017      2           A
4         Test3         4/9/2017      3           D
```

Note: EffectiveDate is in MM/DD/YYYY format.

I tried with below code but its not working.

```
var records2 = from q in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               let sortorder= q.Field<string>("AscOrDesc") == "A" ?
               "q.Field<DateTime>(\"EffectiveDate\") ascending": 
               "q.Field<DateTime>(\"EffectiveDate\") descending"
               orderby q.Field<int>("PrintOrder"),sortorder
               select q;
```

what I am doing wrong in above code ?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for the ordering of rows to be specified *in the rows* - what if one row has AscOrDesc set to 'A' and the other has AscOrDesc set to 'D'? How would those two rows be compared?

Comment: Never used LINQ to SQL, but does that even work what you are doing? Talking about the string you are building, does LINQ to SQL parse that string and do the magic? I kinda of believe that it will just do orderby that string so totally dummy... but maybe?!?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, For each documentname will have specific "AscOrDesc" value. So if same documentname appears two times "AscOrDesc" will be same.

Comment: Hi @RandRandom, Its typo I have corrected code.

Comment: But what if you have two *different* documents with the same PrintOrder value? Basically what you're asking for doesn't make sense in a logical way, IMO. Things you may know about the data don't really help to express an on-the-face-of-it-illogical query order. You really need to be able to compare any two rows, and do so in a consistent way.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Lets say we have two tables. Parent table "DocumentCodes" which list documentnames which is having columns DID,DocumentName,PrintOrder and AscOrDesc And child table "Documents" which is having column ID,DID,EffectiveDate. This table store records of documents we create. We are getting above datatable by joining "DocumentCodes" and "Documents" table.

Comment: That doesn't make it any easier to express a comparison between two arbitrary rows though. Again, *you* know that you'll never have two rows with the same print order but different AscOrDesc values, but you need to express the logic to compare *arbitrary* rows.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added example in question.

Comment: You didnt get my point at all, you are building a STRING not code, it doenst matter what you write... your code could look like this: ``var records2 = from q in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               let sortorder= q.Field<string>("AscOrDesc") == "A" ?
               "HELLO WORLD": 
               "DLROW OLLEH"
               orderby q.Field<int>("PrintOrder"),sortorder
               select q;``. You are constructing a STRING and it will orderby with this string, which will always result in the same, again you need to write code for it to work!!!

Comment: Additionally it seems you didnt get @JonSkeet 's comment aswell. Tell us what should happen if your row with ``ID = 3`` has ``AscOrDesc = D``. With this you have 2 rows with the same ``PrintOrder`` but with different ``AscOrDesc`` values, should it now be sorted ascending or descending and what is the logic to get to this result?

Comment: @RandRandom, Yes "string not code" part  I understand now. Thank you. 
And about "2 rows with same printorder with different AscOrDesc values". What I meant to say if DocumentNames appear multiple times we need to consider AscOrDesc and sort by effectivedate.

Comment: That still doesnt answer the question, you just changed the column we are talking about. So my question again would be "2 rows with same ``DocumentNames`` and different ``AscOrDesc`` values" what do we do ascending or descending and whats the logic to figure out if its the one or the other?!? @JonSkeet - to let ya know

Comment: @RandRandom, If we look into Documentcodes table, each Documentcodes will have specific value of AscOrDesc values. So If 2 rows have same documentnames then AscOrDesc will be same right. AscOrDesc will not change  if documentnames appear multiple times in documents table.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you have time, I would love your feeback to my answer. Maybe you can give a "simpler" than mine.

Comment: @RandRandom: I've come up with an alternative which is ugly, but should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation is a fairly ugly one, given that two result rows could theoretically be compared which have the same `PrintOrder` but different `AscOrDesc` values. It's only the source of the data that's preventing that.

I do have a horrible hack that I believe should work, but I'm really not proud of it. Basically, imagine that the date is a number... ordering by descending date is equivalent to ordering by the negation of the "date number". For `DateTime`, we can just take the `Ticks` value, leading to:

```
var records2 = from q in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               let ticks = q.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate").Ticks * 
                   (q.Field<string>("AscOrDesc") == "A" ? 1 : -1)
               orderby q.Field<int>("PrintOrder"), ticks
               select q;
```

Ugly as heck, but it should work...

Comment: Nice idea, for sure shorter than my approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty ugly, but couldnt figure out something better that fits your needs.
Maybe you have luck and @JonSkeet will come by again. :)

(Used LINQ To Object you would need to rewrite it fit your LINQ to SQL)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lstFoos = new List<Foo>() {
        new Foo() { Id = 1, DocumentName = "Test2", EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 9), PrintOrder = 2, AscOrDesc = "A" },
        new Foo() { Id = 2, DocumentName = "Test1", EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 5), PrintOrder = 1, AscOrDesc = "D" },
        new Foo() { Id = 3, DocumentName = "Test2", EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 8), PrintOrder = 2, AscOrDesc = "A" },
        new Foo() { Id = 4, DocumentName = "Test3", EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2017, 4, 9), PrintOrder = 3, AscOrDesc = "D" },
        };

    var result = lstFoos.OrderBy(x => x.PrintOrder).GroupBy(x => x.DocumentName).SelectMany(x =>
    {
        if (x.Count() > 1)
        {
            var ascOrDesc = x.First().AscOrDesc;
            return new List<Foo>(ascOrDesc == "A" ? x.OrderBy(y => y.EffectiveDate) : x.OrderByDescending(y => y.EffectiveDate));
        }

        return new List<Foo>() {x.First()};
    });

    foreach (var foo in result)
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public int PrintOrder { get; set; }
    public string AscOrDesc { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {Id} | DocumentName: {DocumentName} | EffectiveDate: {EffectiveDate} | PrintOrder: {PrintOrder} | AscOrDesc: {AscOrDesc}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a TYPO, Hope this works

```
           var records2 = from q in datatable.AsEnumerable()
           orderby q.Field<int>("PrintOrder")
           orderby q.Field<string>("AscOrDesc") == "A" ? q.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate") :  q.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate") descending
           select q;
```

Usually my statement used to be like this

```
 var result = from q in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               orderby q.PrintOrder
               orderby q.AscOrDesc== "A" ? q.EffectiveDate: q.EffectiveDate descending
               select q;
```

Comment: The field names are different @derloopkat .

Comment: Hi @Lakshmikanthan, I have corrected the code but still its not working. It will sort by "PrintOrder" but it will not sort by effective date

Comment: The point is that the `AscOrDesc` field should indicate how to use the `EffectiveDate` field - currently you're sorting by `PrintOrder` and then by a *string*. That's just not going to work.

Comment: guys try this data sample (same print order, different date):             const string order = "D";
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable(); 
            datatable.Clear();
            datatable.Columns.Add("PrintOrder", typeof(int));
            datatable.Columns.Add("EffectiveDate", typeof(DateTime));
            datatable.Columns.Add("AscOrDesc");
            datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 5, DateTime.Now, order});
            datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 5, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4321), order});

Comment: *q.Field<string>("AscOrDesc") == "A" ? q.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate") :  q.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate") descending* This would return always descending.